# After anaconda upgrade --all anaconda-navigator does not launch

Tags: qt, python-3.x, anaconda

After upgrade --all launching anaconda-navigator raise an error:

> Exception: setResizeMode is only available in Qt4. Use setSectionResizeMode instead.

I am using version 1.6.0 on MacBook OSX (Sierra). Can anyone help. It seems that there is a conflict with spyder.

Answer (score 0):

There is some change with going from qtpy version 4 to version 5. I thought I had version 4 installed, but based on this exception, something isn't quite right. I was able to get anaconda-navigator to launch after editing this file on line 155:

```
anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/widgets/manager/table.py

155c155
<             self._hheader.setResizeMode(self._hheader.Fixed)
---
>             self._hheader.setSectionResizeMode(self._hheader.Fixed)
```

Edit: it appears a fix is coming in the next release for spyder. anaconda-navigator will probably need a similar patch.
https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/3943